# How can I remove chrome opening by default from Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I remove chrome opening by default from Flutter? Chrome is opening by default and I have Android Emulator installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a command line just use **-d** key like: `$flutter run -d $device_id`

to determine the device id run `$flutter devices` command.

if you use an IDE just select a target device in the IDE's UI.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to disable "Chrome" from flutter use this `flutter config --no-enable-web` and restart the IDE.
To check the available device `flutter devices`
To enable it back `flutter config --enable-web`

Comment: this worked for me